# How to persist a git symbolic-ref

Tags: git

We need to normalize our git branching structure.  If we create new branches for the new branch names, it will create a ton of work to update our Jenkins/TeamCity/etc.  Git symbolic-ref refs/head/new-branch-name refs/head/old-branch-name does exactly what we need -- but isn't pushed to the remote repository when you push, so it's got to be recreated every time you clone the repo.  Is there any way to get the symbolic ref to persist?  Or another way to achieve that symbolic link effect?

Comment: What is the purpose of symbolic refs in your project? Wouldn't tags be sufficient (see `git-tag(1)`).

Comment: The purpose of symbolic refs would be to standardize the names of the git branches without causing lots of rework on our CI scripts.  No, tags would not be sufficient -- tags mark a specific commit and do not follow the head of the branch that you have tagged.